# IE7 empty <div> takes space

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, space

I have five divs each sharing a class of ad_tile. The class supplies 3 pixels padding and a 1 pixel border on the left and right side of the divs with a clearfix for the content. If one or more of these divs are empty, the div(s) don't occupy any space. This approach works fine in all browsers except ie7 where the div (even with `line-height: 0;` and `font-size: 0;`) still occupies space. Any ideas how to fix this? Could the clearfix (Gallagher micro-clearfix) be causing this?

Comment: Internet Explorer:
#id , * html #id , *+html #id {
 margin: 0px;
 margin: 0px\9;
 margin: 0px\0/;
 font-size: 0;
     font-size: 0\9;
 font-size: 0\0/;
 line-height: 0;
 line-height: 0\9;
 line-height: 0\0/; 
}
}

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the padding etc being applied regardless of whether is is empty or not. I would use jQuery to hide the `div` `if` empty

jQuery

```
 $('div:empty').hide();
```

CSS3 - For the record a CSS3 solution (wouldn't work in IE7, added for informative purposes)

```
div:empty {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try

```
div:empty {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Though you really should considering using something like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to prevent browser differences.